# Two way data binding with object?

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have the following in  the parent component:

```
output = {};
```

In the child I have this:

```
 @Input() output: GroupCompnent;
this.output.output = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
```

Now I get this structure:

```
Object {output: Array(2)}
output Array(2)
[0]:Object
[1]:Object
```

But I want this:

```
[Object, Object]
```

Any suggestion how I can do that?

I want to achive two way data binding with object, so when I change value to child to be referenced on parent and get that data in parent.

Parent:

```
  output = {};
   <div *ngIf="visible">
     <z-ag-table [items]="gridOptions" [output]="output"></z-ag-table>
    </div>
```

Child:

```
 @Input() output:GroupComponent;
 selected = () =>  this.output.output = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you are currently getting is totally correct. You are inserting an array to a property `output` in your object `output`. Seems that you want `output` to actually be an array. So change the declaration of `output` to an array in the parent:

```ts
output = [];
```

Then in parent, instead of just assigning the value as is, let's fetch the data and then push it to your `output` array. Also you shouldn't mark the `@Input()` with a component (?)

```ts
@Input() output:GroupComponent;
```

since it's an array:

```ts
@Input() output: Array<Object> // or if it's a typed array, change it
```

Then in `OnInit` we can fetch the array and map the content to the `output` array:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  let arr = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()
  arr.map(x => this.output.push(x))
}
```

We need to do it this way to keep the reference between **parent** `output` and **child** `output`.

Answer (score 1):

For a two way databinding you will need to declare an input and output in the child, something like this:

```
@Input() output= 0;
@Output() outputChange = EventEmitter<any>();
```

Have in mind that the output event has to be named like "Change"

---

After reading the comments I would suggest:

```
selected = () =>  { this.output.splice(0); 
     this.output.concat(<your new array>(this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()))
}
```

Comment: I dont need emit if i use complex object, that is two way binding automatically

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now.  Could be that you need _this.output =_ instead of _this.output.output =_

Comment: when i do this.output = .... in parent i dont get anything, i get an empty object again, or undefined

Comment: Any suggestion @kimy82 ?

Comment: I think I need more code. Could you paste the parent and child code.

Comment: i updated my question...this is what i do for two way binding with object and thats it... i just want what i pass from child to be referenced on parent so when i do console.log(this.output) in parent and child to get data

Comment: I think the problem might well be that you are creating a new object. I have updated my answer with my suggestion

Comment: Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'number'

Comment: The output you are passing from the parent  should be an array, isn't it?